# Converting a pyearth model

Tags: python

I've create a model with [pyearth](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/py-earth/index.html), and now I'd like to convert that object into a format that can be translated into other representations (for example into a c++ function).

One approach is to parse the str output of `model.summary()`:

```
$ print(model.summary())
Earth Model
-------------------------------------
Basis Function  Pruned  Coefficient  
-------------------------------------
(Intercept)     No      1.78778      
h(x0-0.245279)  No      1.73016      
h(0.245279-x0)  No      -2.6705      
h(x0-1.22149)   No      0.31407      
h(1.22149-x0)   Yes     None         
-------------------------------------
MSE: 12.2425, GCV: 12.2427, RSQ: 0.3090, GRSQ: 0.3090
```

But that would lead to float precision loss, and seems like it'd be a fragile piece of logic.

Is there a better way?

Comment: There's also this: https://github.com/modusdatascience/sklearn2code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a function `pyearth.export.export_sympy()` which converts a model into a [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) expression.